Systems of equations involving unison and intersection
While studying systems of linear equations in linear algebra, i see that the general definition is that:                                                                over a field F a standard system of equations of n variables is that of the form $$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n=b$$, where $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ are the variables, $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$  are the coefficients and b is the constant term. I could assume a field F where addition is $\cup$ and multiplication is $\cap$, as $A\cup \varnothing=A$ just like $a+0=a$,0 is $\varnothing$ and 1 is (?), this is another question, is there a one in this set, and an inverse? Assuming there are, and even if there is not, what would a linear equation and a system of those look like including the solutions to them?
Is there a one, and are there inverses using only $\cup$ and $\cap$, if there are, what would a system of equations look under that field. Can linear equations be solved not under a field? And can these equations be solved not under a field? If yes, what would the solution look like?

This page might be helpful

This cannot be a field since there are zero divisors, disjoint sets. Assuming you are talking about subsets of some universe set $X$, then $X$ would act as $1$.

However, the biggest problem, is that neither “addition” nor “multiplication” has an inverse. This can be seen easily since $A\cup B$ is empty only when $A,B$ both are. And $A \cap B$ is everything only when we $A,B$ both are. This is still an interesting structure, but it is not a field or a ring.

Did you mean union where you typed unison?

Not quite what you want but related: the power set can be viewed as a vector space over $GF(2)$.
